# Using an instance pattern in a function definition

Tags: haskell, instance, phantom-types

I would like to create an operator for using "phantom typed" units :

```
newtype Length (a::UnitLength) b = Length b deriving (Eq)
data UnitLength = Meter
            | KiloMeter
            | Miles
             deriving (Eq,Show)

class OperAdd a b c  where
  (<+>) :: a -> b -> c

instance  Num val => OperAdd (Length a val) (Length b val) (Length c val) where
  (<+>) (Length  la) (Length  lb) =  if a == b 
                                      then Length (la+lb) 
                                      else ...
```

To avoid repeating instance declaration for each units, I would like to use the types `a` `b` and `c` in the instance declaration to make automatic unit conversion.

**Is it possible to use `a` `b` and `c` in my operator definition ?**

Comment: Could it be that the feature you are looking for is `TypeFamilies` - I'll take this as an excuse to link my favourite haskell blogpost https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/type-families-and-pokemon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because Haskell keeps type-level variables and value-level variables strictly apart. Are you sure you want to handle physical *units* on the type level? Physical *dimensions*, that sure makes sense (check out e.g. the [units](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/units) package), but why do you need different types for different-unit lengths, seeing as they're clearly equivalent anyway? Alright, this might make sense to avoidly costy implicit unit conversions, but why do you define an operator which does do more-or-less implicit unit conversion then?

At any rate, you can't make the result type `c` dependent of the (value-level) `if` statement. Basically you need to write out a type-level `case`/pattern match; the most straightforward way to do that is with multiple instances:

```
instance  Num n => OperAdd (Length Metre n) (Length Metre n) (Length Metre val) where
  (<+>) (Length  la) (Length  lb) = Length (la+lb)
instance  Num n => OperAdd (Length Metre n) (Length KiloMetre n) (Length Metre n) where
  (<+>) (Length  la) (Length lb') = Length (la+lb*1000)
instance  Num n => OperAdd (Length Metre n) (Length Metre n) (Length KiloMetre n) where
  (<+>) (Length  la) (Length  lb) = Length $ (la+lb)/1000
...
```

A more generic solution that would look more similar to your original idea might be possible with [singletons](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons).